# Brunch io -> compass config : error compiling

Tags: ruby, compass, brunch

I using Brunch.io with this [skeleton](https://github.com/scoarescoare/angular-brunch-true-north)

When I start the server, I have an error of the compiler :

```
02 Apr 12:46:16 - error: Compiling of 'app/styles/app.scss' failed. 
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff' was not found (or cannot be read) in ./font
```

I'm not a Ruby expert but I think I can change this into config.rb

```
Compass.configuration do |config|
  config.fonts_dir = "font"
end
```

I tried /app/assets/font, app/assets/font but nothing works.

Please help me!

Comment: `config.fonts_dir = "app/assets/font"` seems to be working for me with this skeleton.

Comment: I can't explain but not for me. Ruby or Compass are relative path sensitive?